# Unable to make a programmatically created UIWebView transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, transparency, background-color

I am attempting to create a UIWebView programmatically, and I need it to be overlaid on another element, so I have the following in my code:

```
webViewScroller = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(47, 80, 226, 310)];
webViewScroller.opaque = NO;
webViewScroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

The last two lines work great to make a transparent UIWebView when it is created in Interface Builder, but since I wanted to create and destroy the view strictly in code, I am creating it like this.  I was expecting it to respond to the same setting parameters whether created in IB or in code.  Am I missing something simple?  I have also tried looping through subviews and making them transparent, but I didn't have any luck with that either. I am guessing that one of the parent views is not opaque, but I am not sure how to reference it to make it opaque.  I tried this as well:

```
[webViewScroller.layer setOpaque:NO];
```

[Update:] I also added `<body style="background-color:transparent;">` to my HTML.  That is not the issue, as it was a parent containing view: the one behind the "shadows" when you scroll out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, I am answering it myself.  I never found a solution to this particular issue, so I just created the WebView in IB, and it worked as was mentioned in my original post.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to set the HTML body's background color to transparent for this to work.

Something like this (or by using a style tag in the header):

```
<body style="background-color:transparent;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, though I had done that without effect. The actual webview is transparent and opaque, it's just one of the parent views that is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use below to make UIView inherited class as transparent. Set the Value of `alpha` as per your requirement.

```
webViewScroller.alpha = 0.3f;
```

Comment: This makes the webview (including HTML content) become transparent on top of the grey parent view...  I am looking to make the view that holds the UIWebView opaque. In Interface Builder, you can set the background as clear, and it works great.  There has to be some way to do the same in code. Thank you!